# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (key ['src_port', 'dst_port'])

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a machine learning project to classify real time network traffic. These are some informations about the code bellow :

- NFStream is a network traffic analysis framework.
- `.to_pandas()` function convert the data into csv file and then convert it to dataframe.
- `ModelPrediction` is the plugin i added to the framework in order to give the predictions about the application type
- Python version: 3.8.12

```
from nfstream import NFStreamer, NFPlugin

# Converting to pandas
df = NFStreamer(source="ens160").to_pandas()

# Data splitting
X = df[["src_port", "dst_port"]]
```

The last line gives error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (key ['src_port', 'dst_port'])
```

Comment: Try printing `df` what does it come out as? `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` means that you cannot use `[]` to access keys of an Object with `NoneType`.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisOram for your answer. I printed df and i got my dataframe with all its variables.

Comment: Maybe you can show the contents of that dictionary. I thought you couldn't use unhashable types as keys, so I don't understand how you have a dict key with a list of 2 strings.

Comment: @theherk i just selected from all my dataframe port destination and port source as an input

Comment: Gotcha. It's a pandas thing.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve it please ?

Comment: Note that you're asking the wrong question. It should be "Why do I have `None` here?" instead. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. For a better understanding and a good question, it also helps extracting a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt no, i didn't help. Thank you for your answer.